# List of devices connected to DataSnap Server

Tags: android, delphi, datasnap, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Does anyone know how to get IDs of devices connected to DataSnap Server?
I made an application which uses DataSnap Server and I want to limit the connection and identify the connected devices.

Comment: Please provide your coded attempts to solve this by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
var
  UserName: String;
  ClientInfo: TDBXClientInfo;
  logmsg: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Note: this event handler gets called directly AFTER authentication
  UserName := TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession.GetData('UserName');
  ClientInfo := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo;
  logmsg := Format('User %s connected via %s from IP address %s',
    [UserName, ClientInfo.Protocol, ClientInfo.IpAddress]);
  // ... 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the TDSServer component, you can specify an OnConnect event. There is a record type called ‘TDBXClientInfo’ which you can get from the ‘TDBXChannelInfo’ stored in the TDSConnectEventObject of the OnConnect event. This record contains the IP Address.

Mat DeLong has lot of useful information about DataSnap:

https://mathewdelong.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/delphilive-2011-recap/